# Display size is affecting my app layout Android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

So I have been building a simple login screen and the display size of the device is affecting the layout and it keeps changing on different devices, New to the android studio is there a solution?

[image: Layout under display - Small]

[image: Layout under display - Large]

[image: Layout under display - Xlarge]

**XML code**

its a simple layout with Neumorphism .

**And I know we can make the layout responsive with constraint but is there any other way other than constraint layout? **

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Admin.AdminStuff.SettingUp.admin_log_in">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/backButton_students"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_back"
        app:tint="@color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/muli"
        android:text="SUMS"
        android:textColor="@color/appcolor"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:text="Please select the Institution &amp; Class"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_students_login"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="#f5f7fa"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinner_programmes_students_login"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.DropDownItem.Spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
            android:background="#f5f7fa"
            android:textAlignment="center" />


        <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
            style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.CardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            app:neumorph_shapeType="pressed">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/registrationNumber_studentslogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/no_background"
                android:hint="Email Id"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />


        </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>

        <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
            style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.CardView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:neumorph_shapeType="pressed">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/password_studentslogin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/no_background"
                android:hint="Password"
                android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor" />


        </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>


    </LinearLayout>

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/forgotpassword_students"
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:text="Forgot Password?"
        android:textColor="#636363"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:neumorph_lightSource="leftTop"
        app:neumorph_shadowColorDark="@color/white" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remeberme_student"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/login_teachers"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:text="Remember Me"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="16sp" />


    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/login_students"
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/appcolor"
        android:text="Log In"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:neumorph_backgroundColor="@color/appcolor" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressbar_students"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white" />

    <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
        android:id="@+id/adminNewUser_student"
        style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        android:shadowDx="-2"
        android:shadowDy="-2"
        android:shadowRadius="1"
        android:text="New User? Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@color/darkblue"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bottom" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `is there a solution ?` sure. make use of smaller sizes, use something like constraint layout, practice more layouts. there can be no solution if you don't give your code though

Comment: Yeah, constraint layout makes the screen responsive. But is there any other way than that because constraint layout is such a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about dimensions.

An android lib that provides size unit - dp and sp. This size unit scales with the screen size and font size. It can help Android developers with supporting multiple screens.

or

Simply use this dependency

implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.6'
implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6'

and then use ssp instance of sp and sdp instance of dp

refer from

https://github.com/intuit/ssp
https://github.com/intuit/sdp

Comment: I just found out this yesterday, it works A okay. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is you are giving bad constraint that wise it differs in all device.
I highly suggest you to read this article so it will improve your constraint things.
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/android-news/constraintlayout-in-the-limelight-6c22b54d9726)

Comment: Yeah, constraint layout makes the screen responsive. But is there any other way than that because constraint layout is such a pain.

Comment: You can do it with another layout such as Linear Layout, Relative Layout but if you asked me Constraint layout is best. Half a month ago I face the same problems that you are facing then I found this article and It solve my issues.I highly suggest you to read that article you will definitely resolve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

Because every device has different ratios, so the controls may get their position changed in different devices.
So for this purpose you should use Constraint Layout. Set the constraints and now your application should work.

It is true that using constraint layout is time consuming. But it is the best option to maintain the position of controls

Otherwise use Linear Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ConstraintLayout for this purpose. It works well for me. Just change your layout to ConstraintLayout and set all the constraints according to your needs. Hope this works.

Comment: Yeah, constraint layout makes the screen responsive. But is there any other way than that because constraint layout is such a pain.

Answer (score 0):

**If you need to create responsive layout here is some options**

- Use Constaint Layout
- build your layout with `wrap_content` and `match_parent` as possible
- Try out `layout_weight` when you are using linear layout

**Here is some resource to create responsive layout**

1. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout
2. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout

Hope you helpful!

Comment: Yeah, constraint layout makes the screen responsive. But is there any other way than that because constraint layout is such a pain.

Comment: Use Linear layout